# Where can I get my mainnet genesis hash for my private ethereum network to replace in config.go?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am attempting to update the config.go file parameter

```
MainnetGenesisHash = common.HexToHash("0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3")
```

How can I get this value from my own private ethereum network please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas.

You should be able to get the hash of your Genesis block by running `eth.getBlock(0)` (under the `hash:` entry in the output). This would be the easiest way.

Alternatively, if you run the appropriate test code (i.e. basically the code in `genesis_test.go`), the tests will fail saying there's a mismatch between the hard-coded value (that you're trying to change) and the actual hash of your genesis block. Simply use the hash value it spits out in the error message. (Or convert it back to `hex`.)

There error message is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/6d6a5a93370371a33fb815d7ae47b60c7021c86a/core/genesis_test.go#L34):

```
if block.Hash() != params.MainnetGenesisHash {
    t.Errorf("wrong mainnet genesis hash, got %v, want %v", block.Hash(), params.MainnetGenesisHash)
}
```

See the [Testing](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Developers'-Guide#testing) section of the Developer's Guide for details on how to run the tests. (There's also the [Testing](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Testing) page on the wiki, but I'm unsure how up to date it is.)